# Python - Selenium (XPath) "Message: no such element: Unable to locate element"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

im trying to interact with a website. I want to apply some filters but i have an error, my code does not recognize the xpath.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options=Options()
options.add_argument('--windoes-size=1920,1080')
driver=webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://dexscreener.com/polygon/uniswap")

folder=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//button[@class="chakra-button chakra-menu__menu-button custom-tpjv8u"]')
folder.click()
folder=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//button[@id="menu-list-36-menuitem-33"]')
folder.click()
```

Comment: This is the HTML code: <button type="button" value="h6" id="menu-list-36-menuitem-33" role="menuitemradio" tabindex="-1" aria-checked="true" class="chakra-menu__menuitem-option custom-13c7rae" data-index="2"><span class="chakra-menu__icon-wrapper custom-usinoq"><svg viewBox="0 0 14 14" width="1em" height="1em" focusable="false" aria-hidden="true" class="chakra-menu__icon"><polygon fill="currentColor" points="5.5 11.9993304 14 3.49933039 12.5 2 5.5 8.99933039 1.5 4.9968652 0 6.49933039"></polygon></svg></span><span style="flex: 1 1 0%;">Last 6 hours</span></button>

Answer (score 1):

You should use another XPATH for option choosing.
Seems like ids for options may be generated dynamically.

So you can try following XPATHs for different filters:

```
//button[@value="m5"]   # Last 5 minutes button
//button[@value="h1"]   # Last hour
//button[@value="h6"]   # Last 6 hours
//button[@value="h24"]  # Last 24 hours
```

This way it works fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using CSS_SELECTOR? I was working with Selenium recently, and sometimes when XPATH was not working, CSS_SELECTOR was.

```
folder=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "selector here")
```